# How to put an <include> full screen in my layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to have an  that will include a layout that contains a progress bar. The problem is that the background does not fill in the bottom and in the top, and I want that the background goes in front of the bottom navigation bar and the bottom bar. Here is a image of the problem.

[image]

Here is my include

```
 <include
                android:id="@+id/loadingProductDetails"
                layout="@layout/dialog_login"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is my full layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                style="@style/RepsolText"
                android:id="@+id/categoryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewOffersByCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/loginLoadingProduct"
            layout="@layout/dialog_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Is the bottom bar part of another layout? I can't see it here

Comment: Yes, the bottom bar belongs to the mainactivity, this is a fragment.

Comment: Perhaps you should move the loading view to your activity, i dont think you can draw over a parents view a child is not even part of